# Why can we MOV the address of a 64-bit value into a 32 bit register?

Tags: assembly, x86, masm

```
list QWORD 1234567812345678h
.code
main proc

    mov eax  ,offset list
```

Why 32 bit register accept the 64 bit.

MOV is flexible in using operands, as long as the following rules are observed:
 Both operands must be the same size.

all register follow the rule above except 32 bit why

Comment: `offset` loads the address which is 32 bits so it fits. Even if you tried to load from memory, you'd just get the first 32 bits of the value (assuming your assembler does not do type checking).

Comment: If you'd tried this in a debugger, you would have seen that it OFFSET gave you the address not the value.  I put that in the title for you; but IDK if you realized that's what your code was doing.  You might want to edit again with some title that makes the question make sense, but still matches the code.

Comment: Key point is that if you run this with the debugger you can answer these questions for yourself. Experiment, it's free!